# Re-expressing matrices in another form.

Tags: matrices

How do I go about writing

$(a x_0+by_0)\begin{bmatrix}q\\r\end{bmatrix} e$<sup>λ<sub>1</sub>t</sup> + $(cx_0+dy_0)\begin{bmatrix}s\\t\end{bmatrix}$e<sup>λ<sub>2</sub>t</sup>

in the form

$\begin{bmatrix} w&x\\ y&z \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{bmatrix}$

Where a,b,c,d,q,r,s,t,λ<sub>1</sub>,λ<sub>2</sub> ∈ $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$w = aqe^{{\lambda_1}t} + cse^{{\lambda_2}t}$

$x = bqe^{{\lambda_1}t} + dse^{{\lambda_2}t}$

$y = are^{{\lambda_1}t} + cte^{{\lambda_2}t}$

$z = bre^{{\lambda_1}t} + dte^{{\lambda_2}t}$

EDIT:

To see why:

$(a x_0+by_0)\begin{bmatrix}q\\r\end{bmatrix} e^{\lambda_1t} + (cx_0+dy_0)\begin{bmatrix}s\\t\end{bmatrix}e^{\lambda_2t}$

$= [a\ b]\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}q\\r\end{bmatrix} e^{\lambda_1t}
+ [c\ d]\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}s\\t\end{bmatrix} e^{\lambda_1t}$

$= e^{\lambda_1t}\begin{bmatrix}q\\r\end{bmatrix} 
[a\ b]\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{bmatrix}
+ e^{\lambda_2t}\begin{bmatrix}s\\t\end{bmatrix} 
[c\ d]\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{bmatrix}$
 (this step works because $[a\ b]\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{bmatrix}$ for example is just a simple number)

$= (e^{\lambda_1t}\begin{bmatrix}q\\r\end{bmatrix}[a\ b] + e^{\lambda_2t}\begin{bmatrix}s\\t\end{bmatrix}[c\ d])\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{bmatrix}$

So the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} w&x\\ y&z \end{bmatrix}$ you want is basically just $(e^{\lambda_1t}\begin{bmatrix}q\\r\end{bmatrix}[a\ b] + e^{\lambda_2t}\begin{bmatrix}s\\t\end{bmatrix}[c\ d])$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $c_1=e^{\lambda_1 t}$ and $c_2=e^\lambda_2 t$.

Write
$$\eqalign{
(a x_0+by_0)\begin{bmatrix}q\\r\end{bmatrix} c_1 +  (cx_0+dy_0)\begin{bmatrix}s\\t\end{bmatrix} c_2 
&=
\begin{bmatrix}q(a x_0+by_0)c_1\\r(a x_0+by_0)c_1\end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix}s(cx_0+dy_0)c_2\\t(cx_0+dy_0)c_2\end{bmatrix} \cr 
&=\left[\matrix{ q(a x_0+by_0)c_1 +  s(cx_0+dy_0)c_2\cr  
  r(a x_0+by_0)c_1+ t(cx_0+dy_0)c_2 } \right]\cr
&=   \left[\matrix{ (qa c_1 +scc_2)x_0    + (qbc_1+sdc_2)y_0  \cr  
  (rac_1 +tcc_2)x_0+ (rbc_1+tdc_2)y_0 } \right]\cr  \cr
&=    \left[\matrix{ qa c_1 +scc_2   &    qbc_1+sdc_2  \cr  
   rac_1 +tcc_2&  rbc_1+tdc_2  } \right]
\left[\matrix{x_0\cr y_0}\right].
\cr  
 }
$$